# java hibernate Unknown column ' ' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate

I need a help.

When i use `getAllStreets()` method i have error in HQL:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'this_1_.houses_id' in 'field list'
```

I guess he must write `this_1_id` instead `this_1_.houses_id`

May be i did wrong Entity and relation ?

2 entity - Houses and Streets

ER - model:

Table Streets

- Id
- Name
- Houses_id

Table Houses

- id
- name

My Classes:

Street

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Streets")
public class Street {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long houses_id;
    private House house;
    public Street(){}    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="Houses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="houses_id"))
    public House getHouse() {
        return house;
    }
    public void setHouse(House house) {
        this.house = house;
    }
    @Column(name="houses_id")
    public Long getHouses_id() {
        return houses_id;
    }
    public void setHouses_id(Long houses_id) {
        this.houses_id = houses_id;
    }
}
```

House

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Houses")
public class House {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    public House(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My DAOIMP:

StreetDAOImp:

```
public class StreetDAOImpl implements StreetDAO {
    @Override
    public void addStreet(Street street) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(street);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(session != null && session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Collection getAllStreets() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = null;
        List<Street> streets = new ArrayList<Street>(); 
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            streets = session.createCriteria(Street.class).list();
            //Query q = session.createQuery("select str from com.ff.model.Street str join str.houses h where h.id = str.houses_id");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return streets;
    }
}
```

HouseDAOImpl:

```
public class HouseDAOImpl implements HouseDAO {

    @Override
    public void addHouse(House house)throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(house);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(session != null && session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection getAllHouses() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = null;
        List<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();

        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            houses = session.createCriteria(House.class).list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         finally {
              if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
              }

    }
    return houses;
}}
```

Error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_, this_.houses_id as houses2_1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_1_.houses_id as houses3_0_1_, house2_.id as id0_0_, house2_.name as name0_0_ from Streets this_ left outer join Houses this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id left outer join Houses house2_ on this_1_.houses_id=house2_.id
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'this_1_.houses_id' in 'field list'
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy14.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.ff.DAO.StreetDAOImpl.getAllStreets(StreetDAOImpl.java:48)
    at FFMain.main(FFMain.java:58)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_1_.houses_id' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Aaaa! Too many code!!!

Comment: Why do you have both house ID and house in your street object?

Comment: Have you tried to run this query directly? Does `Streets` table have `houses_id` column?

Comment: if you put annotations make sure that no whitespace left

Comment: you should debug your sql query first, if it runs ok then the issue is in java code. but now seems that your query is incorrect in first turn

Comment: @defaultlocale yes, houses_id have in streets

Comment: @user15 how it's "streets = session.createCriteria(Street.class).list();" may be incorect?

Comment: @СултанАбубакиров so, have you tried to run a query from error message? You wrote `house_id` and your code links to `houses_id`.

Comment: @defaultlocale i tried use this query
"streets = session.createCriteria(Street.class).list();"
in sql_log(show_sql = true in hibernate.cfg)
 i see :
"Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_, this_.name as name1_1_, this_1_.houses_id as houses3_0_1_, house2_.id as id0_0_, house2_.name as name0_0_ from Streets this_ left outer join Houses this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id left outer join Houses house2_ on this_1_.houses_id=house2_.id"

It's HQL write house_id
i think instead house_id must id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
@JoinTable(name="Houses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="houses_id"))
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but [JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) is usually used to resolve ManyToMany relations with intermediary table. So this code implies that you have table `Houses` with `id` and `houses_id` columns. Error message says that there is no `houses_id` in `Houses` table (which sounds logical to me)
Maybe you should try ManyToOne and JoinColumn instead? For example:

```
@JoinColumn(name="house_id")
```

or `houses_id` if that's your foreign key in streets table. Plural sounds strange if this is really many-to-one relationship.

Comment: yes, you are right!!
i delete how sad someone and write:
    @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="houses_id")
 public House getHouse() {
  return house;
 }
 public void setHouse(House house) {
  this.house = house;
 }
and it's work..now i need test realtion with house.

Answer (score 9):

Please make sure the table you are calling have the right columns. I had the issue and I found that the mapped domain columns were not matching in the database.

Comment: In a similar vein, I found that somehow a column name in MySQL Workbench had excess lead spaces - not sure how they got there but once removed, the error was resolved. I saw the spaces by using the Table Inspector.

Comment: To expand the comment - also check if your binded field has the same name that in the database. You may suppose you're using some naming strategy to convert between snakecase and camelcase, but you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that, while I used a variable name like userName or bloodGroup, it's getting the error "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.blood_group' in 'field list' "
To overcome this issue change the variable name like username or blood_Group. I hope it will get the excepted result.

Comment: I wasn't expecting this to work, but it did (I had issue Unknown column 'appointmen0_.apptDesc' in 'field list'). Can anyone clarify why this is a solution, and why it didn't allow standard camel case when the camel case matches the DB?

Answer (score 0):

check also getters and setters names on your class, all must be the same

```
    public String getNome() {//wrong Nome
        return name;
    }


    public void getName(String name) {//right
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an accepted answer. I would like to mention an alternative answer to anyone who comes on this page with the same problem - unknown column in field list.

I was trying to pick up Survey details (from Survey Table) when I query UserSurveyLog (which has common SurveyID between both tables) via mapping

Mapping in UserSurvey Table

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "SurveyID")
private Survey survey;

public Survey getSurvey() {    return survey;  }

public void setSurvey(Survey survey) {   this.survey = survey;  }

public Integer getUserSurveyLogID() {
    return userSurveyLogID;
}
```

Look at this error I receive

> Hibernate: insert into hifiniteDB.UserSurveyLog (CompletedDate, CreatedByUserName, CreatedDate, ExpiryDate, LastDeliveredDate, ModifiedByUserName, ModifiedDate, OrgNodeID, ProgramUserID, RootOrgNodeID, survey_SurveyID, SurveyID, SurveyStatus, SurveyTriggerID, SurveyTriggerType, UserDiagnosisID, UserID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   2019-10-09 14:39:45.722 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'survey_SurveyID' in 'field list'

Observe that  survey_SurveyID has been added by the mapping I have made on the Survey Table. Don't know why just doing a fetch adds this column to the Insert on UserSurvey Log that should have been independent.

The way I solved this was by adding an insertable=false, updatable = false on the @join column.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "SurveyID", insertable = false,updatable = false)
private Survey survey;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check your variable names in your POJO and the names provided in the database. When they're not the same this error is thrown.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer to question. Add some description & explain with more details.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether your database has all the tables. If there are any tables or attributes in the table missing, add them to your database and re-add your hibernate mapping files. I fixed this error in that way. I got 2 attributes missing in two tables of my database and once I added them and re-add hibernate, the error was fixed.