# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'vehicle_vehicleId' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Trying to run a simple example. But getting following error. Might be a silly mistake.

Error :

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'vehicle_vehicleId' in
>   'field list'

**Code :**

User.java

```
public class User {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long userId;

  @OneToOne
  private Vehicle vehicle;

  // Getter and setter of userId and vehicle
}
```

Vehicle.java:

```
@Entity 
public class Vehicle {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int vehicleId;

    private String vehicleName;

    // getter and setter of vehicleId and vehicleName 
}
```

MainClass.java

```
SessionFactory sessionFact = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
User user1 = new User();

Session session = sessionFact.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
user1.setUserAddress("USA");
user1.setUserName("John");
Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle();
vehicle1.setVehicleName("Ferrari");
user1.setVehicle(vehicle1);
session.save(user1);
session.save(vehicle1);
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

I am not sure why its not able to create mapping column `'vehicle_vehicleId'`.
I went through following SO answers . But it didnt help actually.

- [java hibernate Unknown column ' ' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066227/java-hibernate-unknown-column-in-field-list)
- [ERROR: Unknown column 'this_.idHardDrives' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508830/error-unknown-column-this-idharddrives-in-field-list)
- [Hibernate : Unknown column in field list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678317/hibernate-unknown-column-in-field-list)

Please Help

Comment: This looks like a MySQL error to me rather than a hibernate error.

Comment: @SamOrozco. Yes . Actually it got resolved after restarting MySQL server. But after running the main class once sucessfully, again I am facing this issue

Comment: Try adding @Column(name ="vehicle_vehicle") above @OneToOne

Answer (score 0):

I could not see `@JoinColumn` or `mappedBy` property in `@OneToOne` that depicts the relationship between two relations. Please go through the below example it will give you the clear idea about the `@OneToOne`.

[One To One Relationship Example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: If I do not write `@JoinColumn` hibernate should create new column in its own in *tableName_columnName* format

Comment: Yes that will be created, but in this case column is there in owner's relation not in the other relation. maybe this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it resolved by adding column in Database manually.